# How to debug "Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'" in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

This is controller

```
public ActionResult login(login ob)
{
    bool mm = db.regs.Any(model => model.username == ob.username && model.password.Equals(ob.password));
    if (mm)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("welcome");
    }
    else
    {
        @ViewBag.err = "Invaid";
    }
    return View();
}
```

and the error in controller is

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Use `==` instead of `Equals`

```
model.password == ob.password
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `==` instead of `.Equals()`

So your code will be:

```
bool mm = db.regs.Any(model => model.username == ob.username
    && model.password == ob.password);
```